# CSS select div with no elements

Tags: css

I need to make a `DIV` that has text but no child elements invisible with `CSS` is there a way to do that?

if this is the html make the node visible

```
<div class="pages_available_text" style="">
                        1
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="Add_Search_Param('page', 2); return Refine();">2</a>

    <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="Add_Search_Param('page', 3); return Refine();">3</a>

</div>
```

but if this is the HTML

```
<div class="pages_available_text">
                        1
</div>
```

it should hide the div (:empty wont work because the div contains text)

Comment: You just want to hide a div using CSS only ?

Comment: yes but only if there are no elements in that div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a JS snippet is your best bet something like:

```
if (!$('.pages_available_text').child().length) {$('.pages_available_text').hide();}
```

Answer (score 2):

A workaround (but doesn't remove `div` used space, just make the text invisible), wrap the text with a `span` (since TextNode cannot be selected using css), then hide it using `:only-child` selector:

```
<style>
  .pages_available_text > :only-child {
    display:none;
  }
</style>

<div class="pages_available_text">
  <span class='num'>1</span>
  <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="Add_Search_Param('page', 2); return Refine();">2</a>
  <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="Add_Search_Param('page', 3); return Refine();">3</a>
</div>

<div class="pages_available_text">
  <span class='num'>1</span>
</div><!-- the span won't show -->
```

Comment: i am trying to not mess with HTML i am trying to do this only with CSS thanks!